# Fast triangulation of unordered point clouds - adding new clouds

Tags: pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am happily using the GreedyProjectionTriangulation class as demonstrated in the [pcl tutorial 4.2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials/Fast%20triangulation%20of%20unordered%20point%20clouds).

Section IV of the paper [Marton, Rusu, Beetz - On Fast Surface Reconstruction Methods for Large and Noisy Datasets](http://files.rbrusu.com/publications/Marton09ICRA.pdf) claims the possibility of inserting new point clouds in the existing mesh.

I had a look at the files *gp3.h* and *reconstruction.h* contained in pcl/include/pcl/surface/ but I can't seem to find any function that would allow adding new points in the mesh
Would such a functionality already be implemented?

More generally, up to what extent is the diamondback implementation covering the (impressive) functionalities described in the paper (automatic alignment of new clouds,  noise correction, density correction...)?

thanks in advance for your help,

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9334/fast-triangulation-of-unordered-point-clouds---adding-new-clouds/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has been answered in the PCL mailinglist. See the 5th message in [this conversation thread](http://point-cloud-library-pcl-mailing-list.967500.n3.nabble.com/surface-mesh-reconstruction-td2626476.html).

---

Originally posted by [Abhijit](https://answers.ros.org/users/60/abhijit/) with karma: 26 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1